# How to check with class?

Tags: jquery

I need some help with my code. I got a problem with the element as I want to check if they has a new class called 'span3hrfor2hrs' then do something.

```
  if (event.keyCode == 37) 
  {   //left
    if(parseInt(current_row) <= 1)
    {
      return false;
    }

    for(var i=2; i< parseInt(current_row);i++ )
    {
      var yellowbgnextdivwidth1 = $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+i).css( "width"); 
      var yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit1 = yellowbgnextdivwidth1.split("px");
      totalwidth_current1=parseInt(totalwidth_current1)+parseInt(yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit1[0]);
    }   
    var currentrowleft = $(".rowSubPgm div.pgmFirstRow:first").css( "margin-left").split("px");
    currentrowleft1 = currentrowleft[0].split("-");
    currentrowleft2 = currentrowleft1[0].split("-");

    if(typeof(currentrowleft2[1])!= "undefined")
        currentrowleft1 = currentrowleft2[1];
    if(typeof(currentrowleft1[1])!= "undefined")
      currentrowleft = currentrowleft1[1];
    else
      currentrowleft = currentrowleft[0];           
      var currentdivwidth = yellowbg.css( "width").split("px");

      if(parseInt(currentrowleft) > totalwidth_current1 && parseInt(current_row) != 2)
      {
        alert("left 1");
        //alert("-"+(parseInt(currentrowleft)-parseInt(currentdivwidth))+"px");

        $('.span3hrfor2hrs').each(function(i,e)
        {
          if($(e).hasClass('span3hrfor2hrs'))
          {
            alert("replace the 2 hours to 3 hour");
            $(e).attr('row2'); $(e).removeClass('span3hrfor2hrs').addClass('span3hr');
            $('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth)+"px" );
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

When I pressed on the left arrow of the keyboard to check for the element to see if they has a new class called 'span3hrfor2hrs', but it did not do anything. There are no alert message display.

The problem I believe are somewhere in this code:

```
 $('.span3hrfor2hrs').each(function(i,e)
 {
   if($(e).hasClass('span3hrfor2hrs'))
   {
     alert("replace the 2 hours to 3 hour");
     $(e).attr('row2'); $(e).removeClass('span3hrfor2hrs').addClass('span3hr');
     $('.rowSubPgm').css( "margin-left", "-"+(rowwidth)+"px" );
   }
  });
```

I don't know why it haven't check with the element. Do you have any idea how I can check with the element to see if they has a new class called 'span3hrfor2hrs'?

Comment: have you checked .hasClass('')

Comment: umm...$('.aClass').each(function(e){ if($(e).hasClass('aClass'){...}}) seems a little redundant, no? Since $('.aClass') returns all elements which have that class, why check it again? Or am I missing something?

Comment: edit: how come you call item by its class and check if it has class? If `.each` opt data, then it has class. `$('.span3hrfor2hrs').each(function() { $(this).attr('hh'); $(this).removeClass('class').addClass('class') });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already only selects elements with this class applied so you can simply

```
 $('.span3hrfor2hrs').each(function(i,e) {
   $(e).removeClass('span3hrfor2hrs').addClass('span3hr');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help raam, but im using this $('.span1hrfor30mins').each(function(i,e)
        {
          if($(e).hasClass('row2'))
          {
            $(e).attr('row2'); $(e).removeClass('span1hrfor30mins').addClass('span1hr');
          }
        }); so i can check it and resize it. problem are solved!